# How to Access values of data members of a LinkedList of Objects in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

If I have a class as follows

```
class Log {

    int rev;
    String auth;
    String date;
    List<PathInfo> pathinfolist;

    public LogProcess(int rev, String auth, String date,
            List<PathInfo> pathinfolist) {
        super();
        this.rev = rev;
        this.auth = auth;
        this.date = date;
        this.pathinfolist = pathinfolist;
    }

    public int getRev() {
        return rev;
    }

    public void setRev(int rev) {
        this.rev = rev;
    }

    public String getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    public void setAuth(String auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<PathInfo> getPathinfolist() {
        return pathinfolist;
    }

    public void setPathinfolist(List<PathInfo> pathinfolist) {
        this.pathinfolist = pathinfolist;
    }
}
```

I have a `LinkedList<Log>` called `logobject`. I have added almost a 1000 objects of Log to logobject using `logobject.add()`.

Now how do I access/iterate these values of the data members from the linked list?

Comment: Is this something more complex than `for(Log l : logobject){}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over these by using an enhanced-for loop.

```
for(Log l : logObject) {
     // Process each object inside of logObject here.
}
```

I would also encourage you to type your `LinkedList` as `List<Log> = new LinkedList<Log>()`, so you don't run into issues with retrieving elements from your `LinkedList`.

Comment: The doubt I am asking is also about the value of each object.

Comment: For example let us say I want to iterate "auth" of each object,what do I do?

Comment: If you want the `auth` field from each object, you would access it inside of the loop as `l.getAuth()`.  You bind `l` to each object every time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Log log : logobject)
 {
    // do something with log
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the available API of the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, for example

```
for( Log log : logobject ){

}
```

See also the [Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: +1 for collections tutorial link and for teaching me that you can make a code block a hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be this:

```
for(Log log : logobject){
    //Do what you want with log...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `for each` loop introduced from **java 1.5**

```
for (Log l : logobject)
 {
    // Here you can do the desired process.
 }
```